# How do i use sublime text find and replace files to only find and replace .html files only

Tags: html, sublimetext

I am using Sublime Text to edit HTML markup. I need some markup to be added *only to HTML files* in the project, e.g.:

Find:

```
<head>
```

Replace:

```
<head>
<!-- Here is a script -->
```

Is it possible to make the Find & Replace tool ignore non-HTML files?

I have done a Find and Replace in files search but it has changed another file which I do not want it to change.

Comment: Which other file was changed? How was it related to the files that were changed? Was it an HTML file in the directory tree you chose, or opened in the editor if you chose that option?

Comment: Do you have any reason to do it in ST? It's a simple `find` + `sed` in terminal, so what's the point of doing it with editor? Do you perform such updates on daily basis (and even then it's questionable)?

Comment: You would put `*.html` in the `Where: field, which constrains over what files the find and/or replace will occur. If you leave it blank it will apply to every file in all of the open folders, as well as any file that happens to be open even if it's not contained within a folder you have open.